# Linking into a C# event (via a COM .DLL) from a C++ app

Tags: c#, dll, com, c++-cli

I have a C# DLL that is used by a C# app, and it now needs to be also used by a C++ app for the same functionality. To save having to re-write it, it was packaged up and installed as a COM library, and I have it linked into the C++ app, and calls from the app to test methods in the library are working. I do not, however, know how to use a C# event (subscribe to it) from within a C++ app. All the examples I've seen so far, haven't panned out for me.

This is the C# DLL side:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("32529FAE-6137-4c62-9945-DE4198FA9D1B")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IEventServer
{

        //C# Implementation
        event Action<string> EventServerCall;
        event Action<string> EventServerMessage;

        //C++ Implemenation
        event EventServerCallDelegate cEventServerCall;
        event EventServerMessageDelegate cEventServerMessage;

    };

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public delegate void EventServerCallDelegate(String message);

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public delegate void EventServerMessageDelegate(String message);

}
```

and then...

```
public class EventServer : IEventServer
{
    //C# Implementation
    public event Action<string> EventServerCall;
    public event Action<string> EventServerMessage;

    //C++ Implementation ?
    public event EventServerCallDelegate cEventServerCall;
    public event EventServerMessageDelegate cEventServerMessage;

    //Event Triggers       
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public void CallEvent(string call)
    {
        //C#
        if (EventServerCall != null)
            EventServerCall(call);
        //C++
        if (cEventServerCall != null)
            cEventServerCall(call);

    }


    [ComVisible(true)]
    public void MessageEvent(string message)
    {
        //C#
        if (EventServerMessage != null)
            EventServerMessage(message);
        //C++
        if (cEventServerMessage != null)
            cEventServerMessage(message);
    }
```

(the C++ bit are gleaned from examples I've seen where a delegate must be involved).

In the C# app that uses the DLL, wiring into the events is as simple as:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //subscribe to events
    EventServer.EventServerCall += NotifyOnEventServerCallEvent;
    EventServer.EventServerMessage += NotifyOnEventServerMessageEvent;
}

private void NotifyOnEventServerCallEvent(string eventCall)
{
    //actions to be performed on received event...
    Debug.WriteLine(">>> MainWindow - INCOMING CALL EVENT:  " + eventCall);

}

private void NotifyOnEventServerMessageEvent(string eventMessage)
{
    //actions to be performed on received event...
    Debug.WriteLine(">>> MainWindow - INCOMING MESSAGE EVENT:  " + eventMessage);

}
```

So in the C++ implementation, it seems to be alot less clear. This is a WinForms app I'm using for testing, however in the end my DLL has to be able to run in any C++ project):

```
#import "EventServerClientDLL.tlb"
using namespace EventServerClientDLL;

    public:
        MainWindow(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Initialize COM.
            HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

            // Create the interface pointer.
            IEventServerPtr pIEventServer(__uuidof(EventServer));

    pIEventServer->add_cEventServerCall += gcnew EventHandler(MyOwnEventHandler);

        }

        public: static void MyOwnEventHandler(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
        {
           //*I NEED TO CAPTURE THE STRING FROM THE EVENT HERE*
        }
```

..this doesn't compile though ("error C2659: '+=' : function as left operand"). The value being passed through the events from the DLL side is a string, and that's what needs to make it to the C++ side.

Comment: Your C++ code actually looks a lot like a Windows Forms app written in C++/CLI.  No point in using COM.  Just [add the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47w1hdab%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) to the C# class library instead of using #import.  And your event handler of course needs a String^ argument to match the event, just like you wrote it in C#.

Comment: Actually, I was l abstracting out the final implementation, but I guess I should of mentioned it. The Windows Form app in the sample above is just for my testing. In the end my C# DLL will be used by a low-level TSP (TAPI) driver written in C++. So my DLL really needs to be operable in just any plain C++ "empty project".

Comment: `pIEventServer->add_cEventServerCall` is a method call that accepts a `struct _EventServerCallDelegate *` in parameter, which is an interface class. Create an object that implements this interface and pass it to your `pIEventServer`.

Comment: I wish I knew how to do that in C++  ...I'm tasked with making sure my C# DLL works in the C++ environment, however I know very little about C++. Thrown into the pool as it were...

Comment: If I were you I'd forget about COM. Create a new C++ DLL, compile with /clr to use .NET code, expose a set of native functions/classes for your current C++ codebase to consume, and call directly your C# code from within those functions/classes. For instance, register a managed handler for the event and call a native callback function in response.

Comment: There's a few problems with that. 1) There's alot of code/functionality in my C# DLL that would have to be re-written for C++. That is the main reason I'm sticking with C# for the DLL and using COM to make it operable within a C++ environment. We're talking a few thousand lines of code not shown in the example above because it wasn't necessary for my question about Events. 2) I know zero about C++ so I would have to seek out a resource to do it, 3) I'm out of time pretty much...I need something working by end of day.